# CodeceptJS invalid element state: Element must be user-editable in order to clear it

Tags: codeception, css-selectors

Может кто подскажет, как в CodeceptJS реализовать ввод данных в поле? Сечас использую комманду fillField, но дело в том, что при выполнении этой комманды, кодсепт сначала вытирает поле, а потом заполняет. Может есть другой способ заполнить поле данными? Пробовал прописать, чтобы сначала был click в поле, а потом pressKey с данными, не получается, пишет, что нет кликабельного элемента. Локаторы, кажется, все возможные перепробовал.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но вариант с click и pressKey с данными заработал